# Next.js deprecation warning

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, node-modules, webpack-5

Every time I build my Next.js app, I get a deprecation warning:

```
(node:10504) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph 
API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

And doing what it suggested (`cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--trace-deprecation' next build`), I get this:

```
(node:8508) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
    at ChunkGraph.getChunkGraphForModule (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:48741)
    at CssModule.updateHash (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:343372)
    at CssModule.updateHash (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\mini-css-extract-plugin\index.js:1:7125)
    at Object.name [as getName] (*****\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js:786:45)
    at addModuleToChunksInfoMap (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:1124815)
    at *****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:1127194
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28645), <anonymous>:31:16)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:25915)
    at Compilation.seal (*****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:103411)
    at *****\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:148889
```

The app works fine and the build doesn't fail, but I want to know where this warning is coming from and how can I fix it.

Some Details:

```
next: 14.1.0
npm: 10.4.0
node: 18.17.0
```

```js
// next.config.js
const path = require('path');

const nextConfig = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I tried the classic way of removing `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and `.next` and installing packages again, but it didn't help

Comment: Did you find soltion to remove this warning @Shahriar

Comment: @manoj Not yet :/